# C++ type casting int to union

Tags: c++, c, casting

I am porting a part of an existing code from C to C++. I just have to move the file to .cc, make and fix the errors. The existing code is something similar to this,

```
/* a.h */
typedef union foo_ {
    int var;
}foo;

void fun(foo a)
{
   printf("%d\n", a.var);
}


/* a.cc or a.c */
#include<stdio.h>
#include"a.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 0x10;
    foo x;
    x = (foo)a; // Error when the file is .cc but works with .c
    fun(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The casting of int variable 'a' in main function to 'foo' works fine with C, but shows the following error with C++,

```
a.cc: In function int main():
a.cc:8:14: error: no matching function for call to foo_::foo_(int&)
a.cc:8:14: note: candidates are:
a.h:2:15: note: foo_::foo_()
a.h:2:15: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
a.h:2:15: note: foo_::foo_(const foo_&)
a.h:2:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from int to const foo_&
```

It suggests the constructor calls. I tried static_cast, reinterpret_cast and they did not solve this. I can not modify the union or the function definitions. Is there any way to get this working similar to C ?

Comment: Add a proper conversion constructor to `foo`.

Comment: You could have an (`inline`?) helper function to construct the foo if you can't change the definition. You could also set the `var` field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, unions can take constructors too, so you could just provide one for `int`:

```
union foo {
    foo() = default;

    foo(int i)
    : var(i)
    { }

    int var;
};

foo x;      // default-constructs `var`
x = (foo)a; // copy-constructors foo from a temporary 
            // constructed using foo(int )
```

Or since these things are visible anyway:

```
x.var = a;
```

Comment: `I can not modify the union or the function definitions.` I don't believe this answer will work, given the question.

Comment: The second one would work - it doesn't modify the definition of the union or the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can aggregate construct a union in C++ most of the time:

```
//foo x;
//x = (foo)a; <-- Wrong
foo x = {a}; // Right
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/ODQY9z) for a working example.